# How to replace one symbol plus white space

Tags: php

I am trying to remove input which contains colon and white space, but the input can contain multiple white spaces.

```
ex) (update  :) or (update:   )or (update :) or (update : )
```

Please ignore ( and ) it is just to show how many white spaces.

If I do `str_replace(":","",$input)` it only removes `:` symbol not spaces.

what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array like this:

```
str_replace(array(':', ' '), '', $input);
```

**For instance**:

```
$input = "ex) (update  :) or (update:   )or (update :) or (update : )";
echo str_replace(array(':', ' '), '', $input);
```

prints:

> ex)(update)or(update)or(update)or(update)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all the whitespace and semi colons like this:

```
str_replace( array(':', ' '), '', $input );
```

...or use regex to match whitespace and semi colon after letters only incase you have some at the start you want to keep.